# Angular forms disabled binding warning

Tags: javascript, angular

When upgrading to Angular 4, I am getting the following warning in the console:

> it looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true when you set up this control in
>   your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in
>   the DOM for you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed
>   after checked' errors.ֿ

When doing something like this:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" [disabled]="isDisabled">
```

it's seems that Angular does not like anymore when we use the `disabled` property on form control.

What is changed and why it's happening?

Comment: your question is unclear. refine it. you face some issue?

Comment: There are no issues. I don't understand this warning from Angular that appears in the console.

Comment: you should be declaring corresponding `form-groups` and `controls` in the component code. if not it will show that warning

Comment: This is not the problem. Please read the whole question before writing any comment. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are setting the `disabled` property through property binding, but you are using `formControl` which gives reactive nature.

So, you should be declaring the `{disable: true}` in the code as below,

```
form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})
  });
```

**Note:** If you are using reactive forms you should be having a `formGroup` attribute defined in your HTML.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/084VvnrnYj0wbiVku5Y9?p=preview)**

Comment: I already know what causes this. I don't understand what changes in Angular version 4. In version 2 this worked without warning.

Comment: Refer this [**commit**](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/51d73d3) which shows the warning which was reported by this [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11731)